# How to add clickable images to UIPickerView rows?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIPickerView that is used to select musical instruments, and I have a play icon next to each instrument name that I want to play the appropriate sound when the user clicks it, so that they can hear what the instrument sounds like before they select it in the picker.

I have no problem creating images that response to taps in general.

However, within a UIPickerView, an image that is created as part of the row doesn't seem to receive clicks (I would guess the UIPickerView somehow takes priority?)

What do I need to do to ensure that my images get tap events?

Many thanks!

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let parentView = UIView()
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 60, y: 0, width: 80, height: 50))
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height:50))
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        imageView.image = UIImage.add
        
        let tapGR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.imageTapped))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGR)
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    label.text = "red"
    parentView.addSubview(label)
    parentView.addSubview(imageView)
    
    return parentView
}
```

Comment: Do you want to be able to tap the image **only** when it is the "center" row, and keep all other standard picker view behavior? Or do you want to be able to tap on the image in **any** visible (or partially visible) row?

Comment: Thanks @DonMag - looking to make it tappable only when it is the center row. (It's ok if it's tappable outside, but not required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to add a gesture recognizer to the `viewForRow` view -- all touches get eaten by the picker view.

So, you could write your **own** picker view which, depending on how closely you want to replicate the built-in picker view, could be fairly simple or super complex.

Or... you can add a tap recognizer to the **picker view** ... then check if the tap is inside the center row's image view.

Here's a quick example...

We'll use this as our custom row view:

```
class MyPickerRowView: UIView {

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 60, y: 0, width: 80, height: 50))
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height:50))

    var selected: Bool = false
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            imageView.image = UIImage.add
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            imageView.backgroundColor = .red
        }
        addSubview(label)
        addSubview(imageView)
    }
    func tappedImageView(_ p: CGPoint) -> Bool {
        // let's toggle the image if the tap hits
        if imageView.frame.contains(p) {
            selected.toggle()
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                imageView.image = selected ? UIImage.checkmark : UIImage.add
            } else {
                imageView.backgroundColor = selected ? .green : .red
            }
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

}
```

The only "non-usual" thing is the `func tappedImageView(_ p: CGPoint) -> Bool`... it will check the passed point and return true if the point is inside the image view frame, or false if it's not.

We're also going to toggle the image between `UIImage.add` and `UIImage.checkmark` so we have some visual feedback.

Our tap gesture handler (in the controller class) will:

- get the view for the selected (center) row
- make sure it's our custom `MyPickerRowView` class
- translate the tap point to that view
- ask that view if the point is inside the image view frame

So, here's the controller class:

```
class PickerTestViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    
    let picker = UIPickerView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        picker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(picker)
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            picker.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            picker.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            picker.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
        // create a tap recognizer
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pickerTapped(_:)))
        // don't prevent all the normal behaviors of the picker view
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        // tap delegate needs to be set so we can use shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith
        tap.delegate = self
        // add the tap recognizer to the PICKER view itself
        picker.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.dataSource = self

        // just so we can easily see the frame of the picker view
        picker.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        picker.layer.borderWidth = 1
        
    }
    
    @objc func pickerTapped(_ tapRecognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        // get the index of the selected row (the "center" row)
        let n = picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        
        // make sure the view for that row is a MyPickerRowView
        if let v = picker.view(forRow: n, forComponent: 0) as? MyPickerRowView {
            // convert the tap location to that view
            let p = tapRecognizer.location(in: v)
            // ask the view if the tap is in the image view frame
            if v.tappedImageView(p) {
                print("tapped in image view in center row")
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        let parentView = MyPickerRowView()
        parentView.label.text = "\(row)"
        return parentView
    }
    
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you! This looks like a very neat and robust solution. Thanks also for all the code. I'll play with it tomorrow and come back and mark correct (just feel like I should actually use it first).

Answer (score 1):

Good question. I haven't done a lot with this *specific* scenario but I've done similar stuff with UITableView. Some ideas:

1. Double check the following: isUserEnabled is true for the whole set of subviews from parentView down to imageView? Is imageView toward the front? Maybe make imageView.layer.zPosition closer to 1 and others farther back? You can double check this in simulator with the debug view hierarchy stack icon:
   [Debug View Hierarchy Icon in XCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ky6Wq.png)
2. Work around: Does it *need* to happen on a click or can you just play a small sample when you hit the didSelectRow delegate method?

Comment: Thanks - I've now set isUserEnabled on the hierarchy as suggested, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I've also tried the zPosition trick. Your work around sounds good - thank you. If I figure out how to do it, I'll circle back to it, but the work around should be good enough for current needs. Thanks!

Comment: Wonderful glad it worked out for you! Keep my posted.